# Directories of Java class files found in Git repository cloned from BitBucket, but I can't figure out how to remove them

Tags: eclipse, git, bitbucket, egit

I created a BitBucket repository of several Eclipse projects, and then used Eclipse with EGit to clone that repository to a new Eclipse workspace to check whether I had put all of the files into BitBucket right.

The projects in the new workspace contained *.class files in their bin directories, and I realized that I had neglected to delete those files from the Eclipse project directories in the original workspace before adding the projects to the repository.

However, the BitBucket web page for my repository doesn't display any bin directories in the various Eclipse project directories, and when I try to remove the *.class files from the repository that I cloned, I get an error message that says, for example, "fatal: pathspec 'EclipseProjects/IndexerUtils/build/uw_solr/CmdLineOption.class' did not match any files".

I assume this means that the class files are not being tracked, but I'm not sure. I don't know Git well enough to figure out how to find out whether they are tracked or not. Their presence does not cause "git status" to say that untracked files were found, but if I try to remove any of them, Git says it doesn't know about them. In the meantime, BitBucket doesn't display any of the class files in its repository, but when I clone its repository, all of the class files are included in the new repository that is created.

Is there a Git command that can tell you whether a specific file is being tracked or not? If the *.class files are being tracked, how do I remove them, since apparently "git rm " doesn't work? If they aren't being tracked, why do they show up when I clone my BitBucket repository? What kinds of basic diagnostic commands does Git have that could help me figure out what state my repository is in?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: You have .class files in your bin because Eclipse built the project automatically right away. You won't see the .class files in untracked because you probably have a .gitignore file in your repo that tells git to ignore bin/*.class or something similar.

Comment: You are right. I had Build Automatically unchecked in the first workspace I was using, but I didn't think to uncheck it in the second one. I added a .gitignore file fairly only recently, but it probably just further confused me. So I guess I didn't really need diagnostic Git commands to figure out what was going on in this repository. I would still like to find out what commands in Git would display all the tracked files and all the non-ignored untracked files in a repository. Thanks.

Comment: `git ls-files . --exclude-standard --others` will list your untracked non-ignored file.

Answer (score 0):

do you have a case collision; try setting following and see if you can see and remove file using git rm command.

```
git config --global core.ignorecase true
```

Please note this "git rm"  removes file from that commit onwards. If you want to remove file **thoroughly** please consider filter-branch

example: git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm filename' HEAD

Comment: Don't use filter-branch rm if you've pushed these changes anywhere. You are rewriting history and that is very bad and will cause issues next time someone pulls the repository.